# Mixed language in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fortran

I would like to create a mixed language program in Visual Studio 2017. It will be a mix of Fortran and C++, compiled with the Intel compilers. As Visual Studio does not accept projects of mixed language, I have to create a Fortran project and a C++ projects in the same solution. But I don't want to have any DLL so I want that the object files from both projects to be linked in a single executable.

Is there a way to do that in Visual Studio?

Comment: You create two different projects in the same solution

Comment: Does the fortran compiler allow for creating a static library?

Comment: Start by creating an Empty Solution then create the projects.

Comment: @drescherjm: Yes, the compiler allows to create static library, but It would be better if I don't create any library at all. But I agree that it could be a "solution" to my problem.

Comment: You'll probably need to use the C ABI as the _lingua franca_ ABI between the C++ and FORTRAN.

Comment: Usually people create their UI in a higher level language then load a dll which takes care of the Win32 functions

Comment: @Eljay: I use the C ABI. My code already works under Linux or compiling it from the command line under Windows. What I need is to incorporate it into a Visual Studio project.

Comment: In theory you can create three projects: One for C++ one for FORTRAN, and one to link. It will require a lot of work to make sure you get everything in the right intermediate folders

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a DLL. Make the project with the main program executable, the other one a static library. Make sure that the run-time library options are identical between the two projects (C++: Code Generation, Fortran: Libraries). If the main program is Fortran the only other thing you need to do is make the C++ project a "dependent" of the Fortran project. If C++ is the main, add the .lib of the Fortran project as a source file to the C++ project.

There are two worked C++-Fortran samples in the [Intel Parallel Studio XE for Windows Sample Bundle](https://software.intel.com/en-us/product-code-samples) under compiler_f\MixedLanguage